# multiple bitmaps drawn while rotating

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an activity that rotates png image by the SeekBar progress. And it draws me multiple needles. why it does that?
The needle and the speedometer are not perfect, they are just for testings :)

In onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

...

```
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rodykle);
    workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap);
    mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    yourCanvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
```

later i use this void

```
  public void drawneedle(){
    yourCanvas.rotate(speed, mutableBitmap.getWidth()/2, mutableBitmap.getHeight()/2);
    yourCanvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    yourCanvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0,0, null);
    yourCanvas.restore();
    iv.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mtr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mindtherobot.samples.thermometer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:max="270" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/spidometras" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: 33]
[image: 69]
[image: 211]

Comment: did you add "configChanges" flag to your particular activity in the AndroidManifest.xml , to not have the onCreate method run more than once ? 
Bitmaps dont go away from the memory so easily, if possible it is preferable to reuse bitmaps rather than create new ones

Comment: Do you clear the inner circle of the previously drawn content?
You can do that with canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you clear the inner circle of the previously drawn content?

You can do that with `canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);`

Also, in my opinion, you need to add the configChanges flag to your activity's tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, to prevent onCreate to run more than once when activity rotates.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

To know that the activity rotated, you need to override the

```
onConfigurationChanged(Config newConfig)
```

method and check the new orientation of the newConfig variable

Comment: if i add `canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);` in the beginning of `drawneedle()` or before calling it, it does not draw anything.

Comment: what about the config changes ?

Comment: Lena Bru could you say more about testing `onConfigurationChanged(Config newConfig)` ? i am not sure if i am able to do it by my self

Comment: are you using any dependency injection libraries ? if so this method will not work

Comment: i am not using anything :) i am not an expert of java, started playing with it maybe 2 months ago...

Comment: while importin `Matrix` there is two option: 1. android.graphics 2.android.opengl. Which one to choose?

Comment: graphics usually, opengl is usually for drawing 3d objects

Comment: Lena Bru can i ask you a question. I managed to rotate image, but if i am doing speedometer i see that rotating needle is a bit laggy, what would you suggest? Draw needle with code?

Comment: why are you rotating the canvas instead of the arrow ? you could extend the View object and create an "ArrowView" object, and override its onDraw method, and avoid the "iv.setImageBitmap" method